# datatables + 2 footers + control which one is manipulated in the footer_callback function

Tags: datatables

here is my [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/HattrickNZ/s4hr6hw7/)

I want to have more control over this part of the code:

```
        $( api.column( 4 ).footer() ).html(
            '$'+pageTotal +' ( $'+ total +' total)'
        );
```

I would like to apply this on my `#total` footer. It is currently being applied to the `#search` footer, and is changing the value of the `#search` footer in the top right of the table, when I want it to change the `#total` footer in the bottom right.

this is with the html like this order:

```
<tfoot id="search">
            <tr>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
         <tfoot id="total">
            <tr>
                <th colspan="4" style="text-align:right">Total:</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
```

I can swap the footers around above, [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/HattrickNZ/s4hr6hw7/1/) here, and it will appear the way I want but the multi column filter search will break. **Can I achieve what I am trying here without breaking anything?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

think i need to replace this

```
    $( api.column( 4 ).footer() ).html(
        '$'+pageTotal +' ( $'+ total +' total)'
    );
```

with this(getting the 2nd `th` tag of the `tfoot` tag with id `total`):

```
        $("tfoot#total th:nth-child(2)").html(
              '$'+pageTotal +' ( $'+ total +' total)'
        )
```

[FIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/HattrickNZ/s4hr6hw7/2/)

An aside(something I want ot understand better):

doing this `$("tfoot th:nth-child(2)").html("33")` in the console here 
[datatables footer_callback](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/footer_callback.html)
will change the value of the 4th column in the footer.

but doing the similar command `$("tfoot#total th:nth-child(2)").html("33")` in the console here [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/HattrickNZ/s4hr6hw7/) does not chnage it, I have to do it within the `footer_callback` function

Comment: i have already solve you problem as you posted the quetion check this out  :https://jsfiddle.net/dipakthoke07/7bh7w2tu/8/

Comment: This you have aks :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40042969/concatenat-data-tables-coums/40043848?noredirect=1#comment67386131_40043848

Comment: @Dipak tks again I think you mean this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40011700/how-to-combine-combine-footer-callback-with-multi-filter-in-datatables)